# Devolver Índice condicional "if" Python

Tags: python

Hola necesito devolver la posición de elementos contenido en una lista (Status), que coincidan con otra lista (Status2) por ejemplo:

```
   While i<=len(Status2):
        if Status[i] in Status2:
            PosX.append(Status2.index(Status))
        i=i+1
```

O sea, quiero guardar en la lista "Posx" las posiciones si algún elemento de Status está en Status2.

La salida es una lista con la posición que se encuentra Status dentro de Status2.

Comment: Hola Jorge, no termina de quedarme claro lo que deseas. ¿`Status` es una lista y `Status2` otra? Si pudiereas agregar el ciclo completo (para saber de donde viene `i` y una entrada junto con su salida deseada sería de gran ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: "Status2" tiene elementos iguales que "Status" editaré la pregunta pero es un ciclo del tamaño de la lista.

Comment: Hola Jorge, yo sigo sin entender. Si `Status` es un elemento que podría estar contenido en `Status2`, al que le tendrías que pedir el índice sería a `Status2` y no a al revés.

Comment: Así es, en Status2 hay elementos iguales que en Status, quiero saber la posición que ocupan  estos  elementos (Status) en status2, sin hacer más que lo que muestro, ya que no quiero caer más grande el código.

Comment: Entiendo. entonces, que ambos son listas que pueden tener los mismos elementos, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Jorge a ver si lo entiendo, ¿quieres que por cada elemento de Status que está en Status 2 se obtenga una lista con el índice donde este elemento está en Status2? Si es eso, ¿existe la posibilidad que que Status2 tenga elementos repetidos dentro de ella? ¿O que los tenga Status? No me refiero a que existan repeticines entre las dos listas, sino a si dentro de cada una los elemntos son únicos.

Comment: Status2 no tiene repetidos, contiene un elemento que coincide con Status, solo quiero almacenar la posición donde se encuentra

Comment: Disculpen, acabo de arreglar mejor la pregunta (estaba desde el celular). Ambos son listas, la idea es encontrar las posiciones en Status2 de elementos de Status[i]

Comment: Jorge acabo de añadir otra interpretación a la pregunta, si no es lo que quieres te aconsejo crear un ejemplo pequeñito con dos lista `Status` y `Status2` y con la salida esperada usando esas dos listas como hago yo en mi respuesta. Un ejemplo reproducible junto a su salida esperada es en la mayoría de los casos más explicativo que unos pocos párrafos explicando el problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si lo tengo claro o no, si lo que quieres es que `Posx` contenga los índices de los elementos de `Status2` que se encuentran en `Status`, entonces basta con usar `enumerate` dentro de una lista por compresión junto a un condicional:

```
Status = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'x']
Status2 = ['b', 'c', 'v', 'n', 'a']

Posx = [i for i, e in enumerate(Status2) if e in set(Status)]
```

**Salida:**

> >>> Posx
>   [0, 1, 4]

Los índices 0, 1 y 4 son los de los elementos de `Status2` que están en `Status` ('b', 'c' y 'a' respectivamente).

Dado que comentas que `Status2` no tiene elementos repetidos puedes usar intersección de conjuntos que es más eficiente:

```
Posx = [Status2.index(e) for e in set(Status) & set(Status2)]
```

En este caso los índices no están ordenados, puedes obtener por ejemplo `[4, 0, 1]`, pero si los quieres ordenados basta con hacer:

```
Posx = sorted(Status2.index(e) for e in set(Status) & set(Status2))
```

Aunque ya perdemos eficiencia al ordenar.